# RapidApi and Swift

Tags: swift, api, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I do not understand, how I can implement a RapidApi in a Swift Project, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
import Foundation
let headers = [
  "x-rapidapi-host": "community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com",
  "x-rapidapi-key": "[your rapidapi key]"
]
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather?q=London%252Cuk")! as URL,
                                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})
dataTask.resume()
```

how do I have to wrap this, so it works?

Comment: You need to create a custom type and add a function to it and then add your code to that function

Comment: Your code "is nowhere". You can't put code anywhere, there is some logic to comply. Well, Playgrounds, and "Swift scripts/command line tools" are different, but "apps" needs "structure".

Comment: thanks guys, I copied it from a playground project and now I understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate you block of code in a method -

```
func getWeatherData() {


let headers = [
  "x-rapidapi-host": "community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com",
  "x-rapidapi-key": "[your rapidapi key]"
]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather?q=London%252Cuk")! as URL,
                                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})
dataTask.resume()
```

}